# MySQL 2 masters N-slaves replication

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

I'm trying to set up a *two masters, N-slaves* replication in **MySQL**

I have setup two masters that works perfectly fine with each other.

It breaks when I add a slave for **master#1**.

*Creating*

**master#1** : Create database `test`.

**master#2** : `test` database gets created from **master#1**'s query.

- creates a `test` database in **slave#1**

*Deleting*

**master#2** : Delete database `test`.

**master#1** : `test` database gets deleted from **master#2**'s query.

- `test` doesn't get removed in **slave#1**

What I did was to create a user in **master#

`create user 'root'@'slave.one.ip' identified by 'slaveonepass';`

Give it replication privileges:

`grant replication slave on dbname.* to 'root'@'slave.one.ip';`

Get the info of **master#1**:

`show master status;`

Add the info from above to **slave#1**

```
mysql> change master to\
master_host='first.master.ip',\
master_user='root',\
master_password='slaveonepass',\
master_log_file='mysql-bin.123456',\
master_log_pos=123456;`
```

Reference:

- [How To Set Up MySQL Master-Master Replication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the expected behavior if you have not set `LOG_SLAVE_UPDATES=ON` on both masters.  Set this in the configuration files, and restart the masters.

> Normally, a slave does not write to its own binary log any updates that are received from a master server. This option causes the slave to write the updates performed by its SQL thread to its own binary log
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_slave_updates

This option is mandatory for all cascading replication configurations, where an instance needs to propagate incoming replication events out to additional replicas.

You should also enable this in any slave that will have downstream slaves connected.

Comment: It would be possible with `LOG_SLAVE_UPDATES=ON`? That's good news.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes @d30jeff.  That should be what's missing in your setup.